# The category headings in the help center should be links to the help categories

Tags: feature-request, help-center

If you are like me<sup>1</sup>, you've figured out that help is divided into 7 categories:

- [Asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
- [Privileges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)
- [Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)
- [Our model](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange)
- [Reputation & Moderation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reputation)
- [Answering](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)
- [My Account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/account)

You'll see these categories in the sidebar when you click on any of these links. When you go to the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help) front page, many of the lines of text are links. But not the categories themselves:

[image: Help center missing links.]

I know the `» View more` link will take you to the relevant category, but my brain<sup>2</sup> would rather go to the specific category I'm looking for (and looking at) than a generic bit of text somewhere below. Can the categories get links too?

---

<sub>1. Not a fair assumption, really. But I suspect some people *are* like me at least in so far as they have noticed this too.</sub>

<sub>2. Not all brains work like this, I suppose.  But mine does.</sub>

Comment: Seems a bit weird to just make everything a link there. Headers are headers, and not linking them seems fairly logical. Then again, as you predicted, I'm not like you. :)

Comment: An anchor tag seems perfectly reasonable though, with a ¶ character on hover perhaps? That's what the Python documentation does and it works great